# Using nested loops with nested lists

Tags: r, nested-loops

I'm trying to compare values to a threshold by using nested lists and nested loops. The list contains a list of individuals, who each get `n` number of trials, where (in each trial) they get two values which are drawn from two distributions. These values are then combined using Kullback-Leibler divergence (KLD), which means that each trial now has one single value. The goal is to find out (for each individual) how many of these values are equal to or exceed a threshold value.

The problem is that the results don't add up. I should be getting a lot of 1s (in my `compare_05`) when the threshold is at `0.5` (according to my calculations). Any suggestions for what I have done wrong? I'm *very* new to coding, so the code might look a bit crude.

```
n = 10#trials
x = 5#people

p_sd = 1
s_sd = 0.5
KL_sd = 0.4472136

rand_values = list(1:2)
trials = list(rep(rand_values,n))
all_1 = rep(trials, x) #nested lists

for (i in 1:x){
  for (k in 1:n){
    for (m in 1:2){
      if (all_1[[i]][[k]][[m]]==1){
        all_1[[i]][[k]][[m]]=rnorm(1,0,2) #adding the random values
      } else {
        all_1[[i]][[k]][[m]]=rnorm(1,0,1)
      }
    }
  }
}

compare_05=numeric(x)
for (i in 1:x){
  for (k in 1:n){
    compare_05[i]=length(which(   #the next seven lines make up the KLD equation
      (log(p_sd/KL_sd) + (((KL_sd*KL_sd) + (all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]]-((s_sd*s_sd)/
                     (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]] + (p_sd*p_sd)/
           (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[2]]))^2)/(2*p_sd*p_sd))-0.5 
   +  
      log(KL_sd/p_sd) + (((p_sd*p_sd) + (all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]]-((s_sd*s_sd)/
                    (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]] + (p_sd*p_sd)/
       (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[2]]))^2)/(2*KL_sd*KL_sd))-0.5)
      >=0.5))/n 
  }
}
```

I made this work when I combined the randomly drawn values using cohen's d rather than KLD.

```
all_2 = all_1
for (i in 1:x){
  for (k in 1:n){
    all_2[[i]][k]=sum(all_2[[i]][[k]][[1]]-all_2[[i]][[k]][[2]])
    all_2[[i]][k]=abs(all_2[[i]][[k]][[1]]/0.7905)
  }
}

compare_d_05 = numeric(x)
for (i in 1:x){
  compare_d_05[i]=length(which((as.numeric(all_2[[i]]))>=0.5))/n
}
```

Results from the cohen's d (`compare_d_05`):

```
[1] 0.8 0.9 0.8 0.9 0.9
```

I don't expect the output to be similar to these numbers (unless you increase the threshold to maybe 2.5 or 2.75), but I definitely should not be getting a lot of `0.1`(or `0.01` if you increase `n` to 100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're defining `compare_05[i]`, it's being redefined for each `k`, so you're effectively doing the following

```
compare_05=numeric(x)
for (i in 1:x){
  for (k in n){#Only where k is n, not for other values of k
    compare_05[i]=length(which(   #the next seven lines make up the KLD equation
      (log(p_sd/KL_sd) + (((KL_sd*KL_sd) + (all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]]-((s_sd*s_sd)/
                     (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]] + (p_sd*p_sd)/
           (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[2]]))^2)/(2*p_sd*p_sd))-0.5 
   +  
      log(KL_sd/p_sd) + (((p_sd*p_sd) + (all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]]-((s_sd*s_sd)/
                    (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]] + (p_sd*p_sd)/
       (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[2]]))^2)/(2*KL_sd*KL_sd))-0.5)
      >=0.5))/n 
  }
}
```

This doesn't happen with cohen's d because you're only using one loop there. If I'm understanding correctly, what you want is something like the following:

```
kld<-function(k, i, all_1){
  length(
    which(
      (log(p_sd/KL_sd)+(((KL_sd*KL_sd)+(all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]]-((s_sd*s_sd)/
                                                                (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]] + (p_sd*p_sd)/
                                                                (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[2]]))^2)/(2*p_sd*p_sd))-0.5 
       +  
         log(KL_sd/p_sd) + (((p_sd*p_sd) + (all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]]-((s_sd*s_sd)/
                                                                    (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[1]] + (p_sd*p_sd)/
                                                                    (s_sd*s_sd+p_sd*p_sd)*all_1[[i]][[k]][[2]]))^2)/(2*KL_sd*KL_sd))-0.5
    )>=0.5))/n
}

compare_05=numeric(x)
for(i in 1:x){
  compare_05[i]<-sum(unlist(lapply(1:10, kld, i, all_1)))
}
```

An even shorter alternative, without needing to use a loop, would be:

```
compare_05<-unlist(lapply(1:x, function(a, b, all_1)
  sum(unlist(lapply(1:b, kld, a, all_1))), n, all_1))
```

Comment: @Rebekkasl Great! In that case, please click the checkmark next to my answer so the question will appear as 'closed.'